# unable to write or create anything on my NTFS partitions

Tags: dual-boot, permissions, mount, ntfs, 20.04

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 dual-boot alongside pre-installed Windows 10 on my laptop (on the same SSD disk, but separate partitions) with a UEFI boot loader.

now I can not write, create or edit anything on my NTFS HDD partitions. I've searched for the problem and tested the below configuration for the mount point in `/etc/fstab` but unfortunately, it doesn't work.

```
LABEL=Learnings /mnt/Learnings ntfs rw,exec,users,umask=000,dmask=000,fmask=000,uid=1000,gid=1000,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

this is the `ls -l` command result on an NTFS partition which denotes I have the right access to files and folders.

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mohsen mohsen    78 Feb 16 21:30  /mnt/Learnings/Note.txt
drwxrwxrwx 1 mohsen mohsen     0 Apr 23 21:56  /mnt/Learnings/TEMP
```

also, it should be noted that:

1. I've disabled the hibernation mode in windows 10 with `powercfg.exe /hibernate off` command.
2. I'm not sure if it relates, but I've recently twice experienced the blue screen page on Windows while I was backing up the disk and also while I was trying to restart the OS.

Thanks in Advance, Mohsen.

Comment: If you had a BSOD, the disk is probably marked as dirty because of the unclean shutdown.

Comment: Have you disabled Windows fast boot from *power options* settings under *Change what the power buttons do* ?

Comment: @muru nothing change with the `sudo ntfsfix -d /dev/sdb1` command. I also unmount the partition and mount it again but nothing changed.

Comment: @Mido yes, I've disabled Windows hibernation mode (because of the large Hiberfil. sys file) before I tried to install the Ubuntu.

Comment: @muru I didn't log in to the windows from the last unclean shutdown. now, the problem solved by logging in to the Windows and restart it normally. if the OS needs to be restart after the `sudo ntfsfix -d /dev/sdb1` command, so maybe the problem also could be solved with that.

Comment: @muru Nevertheless, I'm still not sure. may I accept your suggested article?

Comment: If it was fixed by restarting Windows and a clean shutdown, then the probably the dirty bit was the problem, but I have never needed to restart after using `ntfsfix`.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you have to mount the ntfs partion with read write access as below:

```
mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 /mnt/ntfs/
```

**From man ntfs-3g:**
       ntfs-3g  is an NTFS driver, which can create, remove, rename, move files, directories, hard links, and streams; it can read and write files,
       including streams, sparse files and transparently compressed files; it can handle special files like symbolic  links,  devices,  and  FIFOs;
       moreover it provides standard management of file ownership and permissions, including POSIX ACLs.

Comment: Thank you @Rahul for your participation, but as it states in https://wiki.debian.org/NTFS and also in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions "ntfs" has been symlinked to "ntfs-3g" in Debian's kernel which Ubuntu is based on it. so I think the problem was not because of that, as my test also showed.